# Mysql-trigger multiple actions?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following working trigger:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE *test*.*article* AS *ST*
  SET *ST*.*stock*=( SELECT SUM(*test*.*bookings*.*amount*) 
                     FROM *test*.*bookings* 
                     GROUP BY *article*
                   )
  WHERE *ST*.*articlenr* = NEW.*article*;
END
```

The Trigger creates a sumary-stock over all bookings, no matter which type of `warehouseid` the bookings are.

I tried to add:

```
SET *ST*.*stock_1*=(  SELECT SUM(*test*.*bookings*.*amount*) 
                       FROM *test*.*bookings* 
                       WHERE *test*.*bookings*.*warehouseid* = 1 
                       GROUP BY *article*
                   )
WHERE *ST*.*articlenr* = NEW.*article*;
```

For calculating the current stock of warehouse 1. But this gives me the error "unknown value "stock_1"

I'm sure, stock_1 is there. I tried also to set a second trigger, but Msql does not Support this.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the actual statement that fails? In particular where the part you're adding comes with relation to the existing `SET`, `BEGIN`, `END` keywords.

Comment: I just added the next `SET` after the `WHERE` from part 1. there is just 1 `BEGIN` and `END` and 2 `SET`

This is the error:
MySQL meldet: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'stock_1'

Comment: You might have too many `SET`s! Remove the second `SET` and replace it with a comma. Could you edit the code in your question to show the actual line?

Comment: But i need the set? to set? how should the trigger update the table? without a set?

Comment: The correct syntax for an update is something like `UPDATE table SET a = b, c = d`. You don't need an extra `SET` for the `c = d` part.

Comment: I just found out, that the `UPDATE`-Line is needed again...